# XSL Complex Transform from PowerShell Output

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt, transform

I'm still in the process of learning about XSL and XML schemas but have unforunately come across a rather complicated output from a PowerShell export that I need to transform to a readable format for Access.

Unfortunately has thrown up something rather complicated, and my efforts to attempt to sort it have gone in vain, following the guidance I've been able to scrape :

```
<Obj RefId="0">
<TN RefId="0">
  <T>System.IO.DirectoryInfo</T>
  <T>System.IO.FileSystemInfo</T>
  <T>System.MarshalByRefObject</T>
  <T>System.Object</T>
</TN>
<ToString>Archive Files - Requested</ToString>
<Props>
  <S N="Name">Archive Files - Requested</S>
  <Obj N="Parent" RefId="1">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>Archive Files</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="Name">Archive Files</S>
      <S N="Parent"></S>
      <B N="Exists">true</B>
      <S N="Root">N:\</S>
      <S N="FullName">N:\Archive Files</S>
      <S N="Extension"></S>
      <DT N="CreationTime">2016-02-24T08:23:01.3111895+00:00</DT>
      <DT N="CreationTimeUtc">2016-02-24T08:23:01.3111895Z</DT>
      <DT N="LastAccessTime">2019-09-19T03:00:01.2502407+01:00</DT>
      <DT N="LastAccessTimeUtc">2019-09-19T02:00:01.2502407Z</DT>
      <DT N="LastWriteTime">2016-02-24T08:25:10.3301992+00:00</DT>
      <DT N="LastWriteTimeUtc">2016-02-24T08:25:10.3301992Z</DT>
      <S N="Attributes">Directory</S>
    </Props>
    <MS>
     <S N="BaseName">Archive Files</S>
      <S N="Mode">d----</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
```

Ideally I'd like things to make things flat and have it look something like:

```
<Root>
    <Record>      
      <RefID>#</RefID>
      <Name>Archive Files</Name>
      <Parent></Parent>
      <FullName>N:\Archive Files</FullName>
      <Extension></Extension>
      <CreationTime>2016-02-24T08:23:01.3111895+00:00</Creationtime>
      <LastAccessTime>2019-09-19T03:00:01.2502407+01:00</LastAccessTime>
      <LastWriteTime">2016-02-24T08:25:10.3301992+00:00</LastWriteTime>
      <Attributes>Directory</Attributes>
      <BaseName>Archive Files</BaseName>
      <Mode>d----</Mode> 
    </Record>
</Root>
```

Comment: Is this XML complete? The first <Obj> and <Props> elements are note closed as it is presented.

Comment: This is only a section of it, with generally the information I'm after. I can post the entire thing if that'd help.

Comment: Please pinpoint your exact difficulty.

Comment: @ChristopherPrince yes, having the full structure would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The sample XML in your post looks an awfully lot like `CliXml` - PowerShell's internal serialization format.

You can use `Import-CliXml` to deserialize the objects:

```
# Import from CliXml
$directoryData = Import-CliXml -Path .\path\to\input.xml

# Export to a format Access can consume
$directoryData |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi, yes it was an CliXml export originally and this has solved my issue, thanks! I wound be curious how this could be resolved through an XSL schema, which is what I was attempting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have an xml file you would like to convert into another (less complex) xml.

Using your example (and corrected the closing tags), You could do something like this:

```
$recordTemplate = @"
    <Record>      
        <RefID>{0}</RefID>
        <Name>{1}</Name>
        <Parent>{2}</Parent>
        <FullName>{3}</FullName>
        <Extension>{4}</Extension>
        <CreationTime>{5}</CreationTime>
        <LastAccessTime>{6}</LastAccessTime>
        <LastWriteTime>{7}</LastWriteTime>
        <Attributes>{8}</Attributes>
        <BaseName>{9}</BaseName>
        <Mode>{10}</Mode> 
    </Record>
"@

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'D:\test\complex.xml' -Raw
$records = foreach ($item in $xml.Obj.Props.Obj) {
    # create a Hashtable for the 'S' elements
    $sHash = @{}
    $item.Props.S | ForEach-Object { $sHash[$_.N] = $_.'#text' }

    # create a Hashtable for the 'DT' elements
    $dtHash = @{}
    $item.Props.DT | ForEach-Object { $dtHash[$_.N] = $_.'#text' }

    # get the two values from the MS element 
    # (you could also do this with a hashtable of course..)
    $baseName = ($item.MS.S | Where-Object { $_.N -eq 'BaseName' }).'#text'
    $mode = ($item.MS.S | Where-Object { $_.N -eq 'Mode' }).'#text'

    # output a Record node using the template
    $recordTemplate -f $item.RefId, $sHash.Name, $sHash.Parent,
                       $sHash.FullName, $sHash.Extension,
                       $dtHash.CreationTime, $dtHash.LastAccessTime,
                       $dtHash.LastWriteTime, $sHash.Attributes,
                       $baseName, $mode
}

# create the full XML as string
$newXml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
$($records -join [environment]::NewLine)
</Root>
"@

# save the xml string to disk
$newXml | Set-Content -Path 'D:\test\readable.xml' -Encoding Utf8
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Record>      
        <RefID>1</RefID>
        <Name>Archive Files</Name>
        <Parent></Parent>
        <FullName>N:\Archive Files</FullName>
        <Extension></Extension>
        <CreationTime>2016-02-24T08:23:01.3111895+00:00</CreationTime>
        <LastAccessTime>2019-09-19T03:00:01.2502407+01:00</LastAccessTime>
        <LastWriteTime>2016-02-24T08:25:10.3301992+00:00</LastWriteTime>
        <Attributes>Directory</Attributes>
        <BaseName>Archive Files</BaseName>
        <Mode>d----</Mode> 
    </Record>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT you can do most of the work with a template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@N]">
  <xsl:element name="{@N}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

That's the only part that I can see being a little bit tricky, so I'll leave the rest to you.